# set initial size of multiline textInput based on content size

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a multiline textInput in my component and I set the initial value based on state.

I have set up an `onChange` event handler that adjusts the height of the field correctly based on the height of the wrapped text. However it's only called when I manually type into the field.

So I'd like to figure out how to get the calculated content height from the textField with its initial text.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    _textInput:any;

    constructor(props) {
        this.handleTextInputChange= this.handleTextInputChange.bind(this)
        this.handleLayout= this.handleLayout.bind(this)
        this.state.text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
    }

    handleTextInputChange(evt){
        // This works, but only fires on manual input
        const height = Math.max(35, evt.nativeEvent.contentSize.height) 
        this.setState( {text: evt.nativeEvent.text, contentHeight:height})
    }

    handleLayout(evt){
        // I can't seem to get anything useful from this event
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        for (key in this._textInput) console.log(key)
        //  I can't get anything useful from the 
        // _textInput object itself either
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <TextInput
            ref={textInput => (this._textInput = textInput)}
            multiline={true}
            onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
            onLayout={this.handleLayout}
            style={{height: this.state.contentHeight}}
            value={this.state.text}
            />
            )   
    }
}
```

NOTE: `onContentSizeChange` is not used as it seems to be broken in RN 0.38

Comment: Just a question: why would you keep content height in state? Isn't it derived kind of data? Maybe, just maybe (I don't know details) you can always compute height of the input (in `render`) so there is no difference if you change its value manually, if it's the first render or change was triggered in some other way. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I just started with the AutoExpandingTextInput example in the RN docs, which uses state to store the height. I'm not sure how to compute the height of the text reliably. It would depend on font size, weight, letter widths and so on. Somewhere in the textInput component, it already knows the computed height of its content because it is on the nativeEvent object which is passed to onChange. My problem is accessing that height while not in onChange.

Comment: use componentwillmount function. You can call handleTextInputChange in componentwillmount function

Comment: @BurakKarasoy I could call handleTextInputChange in the constructor, but I wont have the event object to give it. I tried a similar thing with onLayout and componentDidMount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making a regular `Text` element with the same style properties and using its `onLayout` callback to set the height of the `TextInput`. It needed a few padding tweaks to line up properly.

Here are the relevant parts:

```
handleTextLayout(evt){
    this.setState({contentHeight:evt.nativeEvent.layout.height+12})
}

handleTextInputChange(evt){
 this.setState( {text: evt.nativeEvent.text})
}

renderTextInput(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row", flexGrow:1}}>

        <Text   
        onLayout={this.handleTextLayout}
        style={
            [styles.textInput, {color: "blue", paddingLeft:4, paddingRight:4}] }>
            {this.state.text}
            </Text>

            <TextInput
            multiline={true}
            onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
            style={[styles.textInput, {position:"absolute", top:0, left:0, right:0,height: this.state.contentHeight} ]}
            value={this.state.text}
            />
            </View>
            )
}
```

Solution was inspired by [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3209)

Comment: Came across this question when I was having similar problem and was trying to find a solution. I found that `onContentSizeChange` works well for setting the initial height